# Sqlite performance across environments

Tags: sqlite, datatable, dev-to-production

I've been profiling a project that implements SQLite Database. The data file (.dat) is 177MB and all I'm doing is read-only queries (a few selects).

On my development machine (SSD) the queries collaboratively run in around 0.1 seconds. Although when I run the same queries on our production and test environments the exact same calls take 7 seconds.

I was wondering what environmental factors would affect this so drastically, surely the difference between SSD and HDD can't be so much slower? It isn't the antivirus, but could there be anything I need to put in place on the .dat file itself? I was wondering if anyone had this issue in the past. It's frustrating because it is performing so efficiently locally on my machine but so differently when deployed.

Another thing to note is that there are more complex queries than others, but the performance timing on the servers doesn't multiply their complexity, it seems to simply add a static time period to each call. For example:

```
|---------------------|------------------|-------------------|
|        Query        |   Local Elapsed  | Prod/Test Elapsed |
|---------------------|------------------|-------------------|
|          1          | 00:00:00.1135747 |  00:00:01.3858359 |
|---------------------|------------------|-------------------|
|          2          | 00:00:00.0624730 |  00:00:01.3923305 |
|---------------------|------------------|-------------------|
```

As you can see, what would normally be almost double the running time, isn't double when in the other environment. For reference, this is a .net core app, written in c# using `System.Data.DataTable`.

Comment: I know this potentially crosses the boundary of being on serverfault. Let me know if I should move it and I will do so. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you also do other benchmarks relative to the code you're executing, I've been hung up on a database query against a SQLite database being very slow in a VM before, only to find out that the entire VM was slow, so **everything** was slow. Benchmarks of other things showed that no matter what we did, things just took more time and had nothing specifically to do with SQLite.

Comment: OS? File system? VM? Network storage?

Comment: @CL.Windows Servier 2012 R2 and it is a VM. No network storage and I'm not sure about the file system.